# Disable audio speech instructions in mapbox navigation NavigationView

Tags: android, mapbox

I really can't find the option in the docs, is there any way we can disable the default speech instructions in mapbox navigation ui sdk, when using the NavigationView in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey  thanks for checking out the SDK! There's a `SpeechAnnouncementListener` that lets you intercept and the modify / ignore all announcements for the UI.

See more documentation regarding this here https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/milestones/#speechannouncementlistener

Comment: Thanks, i was forgetting to set speechAnnouncementListener on navigationOptions as it was not mentioned in the docs at this part of documentation